# exception `Unable to find entity` after the addition of FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I follow steps from my book (based on symfony 2.0.10, I'm using Symfony2.6.1 with FOSUB 2.0).

I build project with CRUD that display data from db just fine (Mountain controller inside My/BackendBundle).

Then I want display project only for logged user admin (with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, that exist in my for_user table inside db with CRUD data).

But when openning ../web/ its result exception `Unable to find Mountain entity`. from Mountain controller showAction($id)

```
#\src\My\BackendBundle\Controller\MountainController.php
/**
 * Finds and displays a Mountain entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="mountain_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBackendBundle:Mountain')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Mountain entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
```

AppKernel.php

```
#\app\AppKernel.php
    new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    new My\UserBundle\MyUserBundle(),
    new My\BackendBundle\MyBackendBundle(),
```

security.yml

```
#\app\config\security.yml
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            form_login:
                provider:                       fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider:                  form.csrf_provider
                login_path:                     /login
                use_forward:                    false
                check_path:                     /login_check
                post_only:                      true
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            /
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false
                failure_path:                   null
                failure_forward:                false
                username_parameter:             _username
                password_parameter:             _password
                csrf_parameter:                 _csrf_token
                intention:                      authenticate

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

config.yml

```
#\app\config\config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      ~
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # default_locale: pl
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }


stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            tree: false
            loggable: false
            timestampable: false
            sluggable: false
            translatable: false

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: My\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

routing.yml

```
#\app\config\routing.yml
MyBackendBundle:
    resource: "@MyBackendBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

parameters.yml

```
#\parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: koronaziemi
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: pl
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not too familiar with SF2, but with SF1, after any model changes I always have to clear cache.

Comment: `var_dump($id);` just before `$entity = $em->getRepository('MyBackendBundle:Mountain')->find($id);`. Double check if it exists in the database.

Comment: @Mike Purcell i clear cache every time physically.

Comment: @Aistis `var_dump($id);` display `string 'login' (length=5)` . He get this from URL as he redirecting `localhost/project/web/` to `localhost/project/web/login`. I'm a beginner i still dont undarstand what that mean.

Comment: is this `routing.yml` (from main post) looks correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `requirements` parameter to your route description and also you can skip entity fetching by leaving it for Symfony to serve you:

```
#\src\My\BackendBundle\Controller\MountainController.php
/**
 * Finds and displays a Mountain entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{mountain}", name="mountain_show", requirements={"mountain": "\d+"})
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction(Mountain $mountain)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm(mountain->getId());

    return array(
        'entity'      => $mountain,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

Also, `@Template()` considered as bad practice and it is a better idea to return a `Response` object:

```
#\src\My\BackendBundle\Controller\MountainController.php
/**
 * Finds and displays a Mountain entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{mountain}", name="mountain_show", requirements={"mountain": "\d+"})
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showAction(Mountain $mountain)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm(mountain->getId());

    return $this->render(
        'MyBackendBundle:Mountain:show',
        array(
            'entity'      => $mountain,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: is this necessary to replace `id` to `mountain`? this will cause many other exceptions associated with `view` and other actions that required `id` like editAction. This all Moutain Controller is generated by command CRUD, why correct this.

Comment: It is not! Just try to add the `requirements` parameter in the action annotations.

Comment: This `requirements`  trick works! I pick it as a answear, but im sure the key to solve the problem is in conf files. Why he gets `/login` as a parameter?

Comment: My guess: the same `/` path gets overwritten. I mean, you are redirected for a login, but the login path is overwritten by an action route. Be adding `requirements` we create a more specific route rule, so it is no overlapping anymore. In my practice, usually the URL becomes like `/mountain/{id}`, but it depends on your needs.

Comment: author of book skip a step where he modify  `@Route("/{id}"` to `@Route("/{id}/show"` and din't mention that. And this is kind of book where author describe every steps. Thats why I started find causes in conf files and focus on maybe oudated version of symfony desribed by this 2012 book. Now it's clear and simple. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

----edit---

@Aistis with this code

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="mountain_show", requirements={"id": "\d+"}))
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    var_dump($id);
    $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBackendBundle:Mountain')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Mountain entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

it's works. But why he gets `/login` as a parameter?

Comment: It is not necessary to use `Mountain` in the action parameters. I just gave an advice :) Anyways, your original code should work just with `requirements` parameter added in the annotations. I am not sure about the `security.yml` config though. P.S. I do not like Symfony 2.3 CRUD generation. It is up to you how you will implement it.