# How to set configure to not receive parameter from url when you have Action with @Route {$param}?

Tags: symfony

beginner question.

if you have action that receive parameter from URL like this

```
    /**
    * @Route("/{id}")
    * @Template()
    */
   public function showAction($id)
   {
       return array('entity'=> $id);
   }
```

And if you want user to login behind `../web/login` url.

How to set configure to not receive that `login` from url as a parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by "not to receive parameter"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [exception \`Unable to find entity\` after the addition of FOSUserBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088122/exception-unable-to-find-entity-after-the-addition-of-fosuserbundle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you should build your URL better.

But you can avoid the behavior you are describing by adding validation rule (= requierement) to the {id} param.

I'm assuming that this id is an integer. Then you can simply do the following:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
}
```

This will match only if the id is a integer. Otherwise it will look for the next available route.